# CSS gradient animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have a button (anchor) that has a CSS3 gradient on it.
I want to animate/fade the gradient to one color when the user hovers over the button.
The problem is I can't find how to do this- since jQuery UI animation on colors works only on regular ones, not gradients.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a CSS3 animation, although they aren't supported on all browsers.  This page has an example of changing the background colour, obviously you'd need to add the gradient.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/

Comment: Thanks. What should I do for older browsers? Should I use svg?

Comment: This page does not change the background color, it changes the opacity.

Comment: @DoctorMick I tried using a CSS3 transition, but it works when hovering, and when leacing the button- it doesn't animate. Any ideas?  -transition: background 1s ease-in-out

Answer (score 5):

I've wrote a jQuery Plugin for animating Css3 Gradients for browsers that support it.

You can find it [here](http://www.webmuse.co.uk/projects/jquery-gradient-animations-plugin/)

It uses a Gradient cssHook I wrote for normalising CSS3 gradients to make it easier to use.

You would use it like:

```
$("#elem").animateGradient('linear-gradient(red, blue)', 1000);
```

It uses `$.queue` and `$.dequeue/next()` so you can also add on other animations.

It needs a gradient to be set first for this to work.

The problem with animation is that jQuery usually does it on the CSS Property value, not a number for instance, that's within a value.

Answer (score 0):

Check this jquery library called [Backgroundor](https://github.com/KhaledElAnsari/backgroundor), I wrote it myself.

It so easy just type `$('#divId').backgroundor();` and it will work, also there's plenty of options in it. check them:

```
// the values here are the default values
options = {
  opacityval    : 0; // int, only 1 or 0 are accepted now (can be boolean too)
  intervaltime  : 100; // int, interval time value
  values        : [0,51,75]; // array of int, default percentage values for the linear gradient colors
  colors        : ['#499bea','#207ce5','#1679e3']; // array of string (hex values), default colors for the linear gradient
  color         : '#000000'; // string (hex value), default color for opacity animation
  animspeed     : 'linear'; // string, default animation curve
  animdegree    : '90deg'; // string, default linear-gradient degree
}
```